# How to bind to collection 2 deep?

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I have the following collection structure and need to bind a combo box to it:

```
MainCollection.Items
```

Items contains a list of elements I'd like to display as choices in a combo box. MainCollection is of type List.  Items is of type List.  There is a Name property on the Item class that I'd like to display in the combo box.

The layout will be setup as a grid.  Each row will have a combo box.

I'm not sure how to access properties on Item elements inside the Items collection.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MainCollection}"></ComboBox>
```

How should this be setup?

Comment: Show what you have for a layout so far

Comment: Not much but I've updated the post.

Comment: So what distinguishes which item in the `MainCollection` get its `Items` bound to the combobox?

Comment: If the layout will be set up as a grid then why would you start with ComboBox?  You have make no effort.

Comment: @Shoe, I'm not sure what you mean.  Items is a List<Item>.  There is a Name property on the Item class that I'd like to display in the combo box.

Comment: What is `MainCollection`? A Collection?

Comment: List<Items>.  I've updated the question.

Comment: Anyone have some suggestion or maybe a website that demonstrates how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

So If I understand the question correctly, you would like to have a DataGrid, with each row containing a Combobox, and the values available inside must be the Name property of the Item objects that are in the *List Items*

You didn't said what kind of data you want to show in each row, let's take a simple User :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

With Item having a Name (let's keep it simple for the example) :

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now that we have the models, we can set the DataContext with random Users and Items :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Could also be
    // public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Creating our list of Items
        Items = new List<Item> { 
            new Item { Name = "firstItem" },
            new Item { Name = "secondItem" },
            new Item { Name = "thirdItem" },
        };

        // Somes users for the example
        Users = new List<User>{
            new User { Id = 1, Name = "Bill", Item = new Item { Name = "firstItem" }},
            new User { Id = 2, Name = "Steeve", Item = new Item { Name = "secondItem" }}
        };

        // Don't forget to set the datacontext
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And now the XAML :

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="testGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                SelectedValuePath="Name"
                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Item.Name}"
                Header="Item">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The result :

[image: Combobox in datagrid]

Hope that the answer you were looking for :)