# Why doesn't TextBlock bind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I run this simple wpf app, I get a blank window.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
//MainWindow.xaml.cs
public string SimpleText {get;set;}
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  SimpleText = "this is a test";
}

//MainWindow.xaml
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding SimpleText}" Width="200"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the `DataContext`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SimpleText = "this is a test";
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

As an alternative, you can set `DataContext` on the side XAML like this:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="TextBlockDontBind.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:this="clr-namespace:TextBlockDontBind"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <this:TestData />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SimpleText}" Width="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public class TestData
{
    private string _simpleText = "this is a test";

    public string SimpleText
    {
        get
        {
            return _simpleText;
        }

        set
        {
            _simpleText = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case to update a property, for a Class must implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface.

Comment: Thanks!  You can also set the DataContext before the text assignment.

Comment: Expanding on this example, do you have any idea why this scenario displays a blank window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767121/how-to-bind-to-collection-2-deep?  DataContext is now set but still nothing.

Comment: @4thSpace: Please see my edit where I described an alternative for setting `DataContext`. Okay, I see this question.

Answer (score 2):

DataContext is a way to go but you can also use `RelativeSource` markup extension to get window's property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SimpleText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                          Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Width="200"/>
```

Comment: Yeah I just provided with another way to achieve that without setting DataContext.